# Displaying thumbnails php

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem with displaying linked images. The code displayed is currently in a .php file. What this code is meant to do, is to get all of the images in the directory that the file is in and display them  (hence the "for" statement). Right now, it just displays a blank page. This is ALL of the code in the file. Also sorry for the code not displaying on the first version of the post.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $files=glob("IMG*");
    for($i=0;$i<$files.length;$i++){
        echo "<a href=\""+$files[i]+"\"><img class=\"thumbnail\" src=\""+$files[i]+"\">                  </a>";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: your mixing up js syntax with php. if you turned error checking and display on you would get the appropriate errors

Comment: Note: [How to turn on errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display#answer-21427437).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $files=glob("IMG*");
    //print_r($files); //uncomment if you need to see the results
    foreach($files as $file){
        echo "<a href='$file'><img class='thumbnail' src='$file'></a>";
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This sort of works but instead of making images, it dumps the filenames onto the page.

Comment: so what are you asking?

Comment: what I want is to have a bunch of thumbnails linking to bigger versions of the picture on my webpage

Comment: mannulay adding all of them would take way too long.

Comment: I have like 200 pictures

Comment: what's the actual html output of the above code, and what do you want it to be (the html)

Comment: http://cmossandy.com/sandy/4s_backup/index.php this is what happened

Comment: you can make thumbnails in html, so I would like an auto-thumbnail maker

Comment: my mistake, i changed the code above

Comment: the problem with your current approach is your just resizing the images with css,  the browser is still downloading the whole file. and your files are large. the usuall practice is to make a separate, smaller, thumbnail file